# Best ways to detect what kind of bandwidth the user has?

Tags: javascript, performance, video

I'm trying to optimize my application experience based on the kind of bandwidth the user has. For example, if the user is on a really slow 2G connection, I would render fewer graphics and less content, for high speed connections, I would include video, animations, etc.

Are there JS libraries that allow you to do this? What's the best practice?

Comment: Your best bet is to write a script that times how long it takes for a user to load an image. Then based off that time compute their average bandwidth. It is not the most accurate of ways, but its an estimate.

Comment: @chrisz that post is from years ago. 2011? That's 7 years. Web is a different place.

Comment: And? The top answer was updated within the last year, and the included snippet works.  Are you looking for an answer tailored to your question when you provided no attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get the connection type for a user you will not be able to guarantee that is working as expected.
I suggest to explore

- [Navigation timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) to implement a guess of the client's current download speed.

This [blog](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/measure-page-load-times-using-the-user-timing-api/) also have good ideas around that.